# Matching fields and creating a new table without unique identifier

Tags: sql

Appreciate the help and consideration. I have inherited a challenge and am hoping one of you wizards can assist. Here is my plight:

[image: TABLE LAYOUT]

My script of:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table_one 1
      LEFT JOIN table_two 2
        on 1.course = 2.course_list
```

Works for that one join however adding additional joins does not return my desired output.

Comment: Please, try to avoid images. Copy and paste your table schema.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Non-normalized table data aside, you would have to do 3 left joins to table 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one 1 
LEFT JOIN table_two 2 on 1.course = 2.course_list
LEFT JOIN table_two 3 on 1.course2 = 3.course_list
LEFT JOIN table_two 4 on 1.course3 = 4.course_list
```

Of course all this assumes a finite number of 'course' columns. Ideally though, you would normalize table 1 into two tables.

Comment: Thanks yes I had it formatted in NP and the resulting paste was horrific: